# como hacer para que un proyecto de windows form funcione en windows CE

Tags: windows-forms, embebido

Tengo mi proyecto desarrollado y funcional en Windows Form pero mi proyecto debe funcionar en .Net Compact (Windows CE o windows embedded) cuando hago el ejecutable este me arroja el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria saber como soluciono este problema

Comment: La librería `System.Windows.Forms.dll` no está en tu equipo/dispositivo _perdona la ignoracia mía_; te sugiero descargar el Framework.NET 4.0 (o el 3.5) = depende de lo que necesite tu equipo/dispositivo.

Comment: yo hago cambio de la libreria y cuando hago el cambio por un 3.5 este me sale error en estos campos

Comment: ´ private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1  private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn codigointegraDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
 private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn productoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cantidadDataGridViewTextBoxColumn;

Comment: Cristian, por favor **edita tu pregunta** con el código fuente. Los comentarios fueron diseñados para pedir clarificaciones, dejar criticismo constructivo, o agregar información adicional. **Los comentarios son temporales** Gracias.

Comment: si yo modifico el dll a 3.5 el datagridview ya no me funciona y me arroja erro que le hace falta un ensamblado